# How to remove all rows of the table but keep the header

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table

I want to remove all rows of my table except the header.

This is what I've tried but it always deletes all rows and header:

```
$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody tr").remove();

$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody tr").not("thead tr").remove();

$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tr").not("thead tr").remove();

$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody").not("thead").remove();

$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody").remove();

$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> > tbody").remove();
```

Here's the html:

```
<table id="tblDetailFourn" runat="server" class="ProjetTable ProjetTableHover">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th style="width:200px">Rôle de Ressource</th>
          <th style="width:200px">Nom Prénom</th>
          <th style="width:120px">Tel</th>
          <th style="width:200px">Courriel</th>
          <th style="width:80px">Actif</th>
          <th style="width:33px"></th>
          <th style="width:33px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The table doesn't have any body rows???  Seems like it worked???

Comment: `$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody tr").remove();` is correct. What is actually happening when you run the script?

Comment: that's only the structure. I fill it with ajax

Comment: Seems to me like your first option should work fine.  Have you examined the output html to make sure the clientID is rendering properly?

Comment: yes, cause it deletes the header and the rows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$('#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tr').not(function(){ return !!$(this).has('th').length; }).remove();
```

Comment: Wow, I thought it would be way more simple than this. I don't know why it doesn't work the way I tried but yours works!! Thank you

Answer (score 50):

```
$('#tblDetailFourn tbody').empty();
```

Comment: Georg!  You're my hero!  This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

Try http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> > tbody > tr").remove();
```

What you have should work though.

Comment: @Marc it may be possible you have a Javascript error somewhere or an HTML formatting issue (missing end tag, etc.) that's throwing JQuery off...

Answer (score 5):

What about:

`$('#tblDetailFourn tbody').html('');`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xCkW/)

Comment: Sure it does.  Check my jsfiddle link, comment out the Javascript and re-run it and you'll see the data appear.

Answer (score 4):

This should work, assuming that you don't have any header elements in tbody.

```
$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?:

```
$("#<%=tblDetailFourn.ClientID%> tbody").html('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the html you provided the solution is following

```
$("#tblDetailFourn tbody").empty();
```

This will work perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblDetailFourn > tbody > tr > td').parent('tr').empty();
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Apologies, basically what is happening is you initially reference the table name (#tblDetailFourn), the > finds the child tags for whatever you reference next (in this case 'tbody'), this finds the child tags 'tr', and for each 'tr' tag found, the child tag 'td' is located; 'td' indicates data row rather than data header (that should be using 'th' tag), this row needs emptying, in order to find the row tag of this 'td' tag, append the ".parent('tr')", this ensures that only the rows that contain data and NOT headers are selected and emptied within the appending of ".empty()'"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete all the tbody including the tag then use

```
$("#tblDetailFourn tbody").remove();
```

it will remove all the tr under the tbody as well as tbody.