# Delete All Rows in Table except the header row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript (with JQuery), I would like to delete all rows in a table except the header row.

This seems like a simple thing because I see quite a few posts on StackOverFlow about this and a lot of solutions provided and accepted. But, none of them seem to work for me. Please refer to my code below:

```js
function delTable() {
  console.log("Delete all rows, but the header");

  // Option-A
  // $('#TableA tbody tr').remove();

  // Option-B
  // Accepted answer for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420203/how-to-remove-all-rows-of-the-table-but-keep-the-header
  // $('#TableA tr').not(function(){ return !!$(this).has('th').length; }).remove();

  // Option-C
  $('#TableA tbody').empty();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body onLoad="delTable();">
  <table id="TableA">
    <th>
      <tr>
        <td>Col A</td>
        <td>Col B</td>
      </tr>
    </th>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Does any one know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

-Karthik

Comment: One thing is that you use `<th>` instead of `<thead>` to denote the header part. Since you don't describe the effects of your "doing it wrong" it isn't clear whether that could be the source or just a typo in your post here, with the problem being elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your th to thead and you good to go, see below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body onLoad="delTable()">
  <table id="TableA">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Col A</td>
        <td>Col B</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function delTable() {
  console.log("Delete all rows, but the header");

  // Option-A
  // $('#TableA tbody tr').remove();

  // Option-B
  // Accepted answer for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420203/how-to-remove-all-rows-of-the-table-but-keep-the-header
  // $('#TableA tr').not(function(){ return !!$(this).has('th').length; }).remove();

  // Option-C
  $('#TableA tbody').empty();

}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pvfkxdby/1/

Comment: My bad! I got confused between the thead and th elements. I will use Option-C in my code: $('#TableA tbody').empty(); It works now!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `th` with `thead` and use `$('#TableA tbody').find("tr")` as follows:

```js
function delTable() {
  console.log("Delete all rows, but the header");
  $('#TableA tbody').find("tr").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body onLoad="delTable();">
  <table id="TableA">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Col A</td>
        <td>Col B</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You set apart your header with `<th>` instead of `<thead>` and then you had `<td>` in your header instead of `<th>`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#delete").click(() => {
    $("#TableA tbody tr").remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TableA">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col A</th>
        <th>Col B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <button id="delete">delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting your HTML in my Google Chrome I can see that the rows were rearranged so that even the first line is inside `<tbody>` tag. Therefore the whole table is removed. You can fix this simply by wrapping the first row in `<thead>` tag or use different approach which does not use `<tbody>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a simple one-liner:

```js
function delTable() {
  console.log("Delete all rows, but the header");

  $('#TableA').find("tr:not(:first)").remove(); // Code to remove all rows in table except the header row
}
```

What the given code does is identify the rows in the table 'TableA' that is not the first row using the command: $('#TableA').find("tr:not(:first)") and subsequently remove the rows using the .remove() command.